# jqgrid autocomplete visible behind edit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, autocomplete, z-index

**Hello ,**

I am trying to implement jqgrid with autocomplete in one of its column. But I have very strange problem, auto-complete list is shown below the jqgird edit form.

I have included following jquery js file.

```
1. jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js
2. jquery.ui.core.js
3. jquery.ui.widget.js
4. jquery.ui.position.js
5. jquery.ui.menu.js
6. jquery.ui.autocomplete.js
```

following jqgrid js file.

```
1. grid.locale-en.js
2. jquery.jqGrid.min.js
3. grid.common.js
4. jqModal.js
5. jqDnR.js
6. grid.formedit.js
```

Following jqgrid css file.

> 1. ui.jqgrid.css

Following jquery css file.

```
1. jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css
2. demos.css
3. jquery.ui.all.css
```

Following code to implement jqgrid colModel.

```
 colNames:['Id', 'First Name', 'Last Name'],
 colModel:[
       {name:'id',index:'id', width:55,editable:false,editoptions:readonly:true,size:10},hidden:true},
       {name:'firstname',index:'lastname', width:100,editable:true,edittype:'text',
           editoptions: {
                dataInit: function (elem) {
                    myAutocomplete(elem, "${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/grid/autocomplete.action");
                }
         }},
       {name:'lastname',index:'firstname', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}}
          ],
```

Below is my entire jqgrid code.

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();

jq(function() {
      jq("#grid").jqGrid({
          url:'${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/grid/load.action',
       datatype: 'json',
       mtype: 'GET',
          colNames:['Id', 'First Name', 'Last Name'],
          colModel:[
           {name:'id',index:'id', width:55,editable:false,editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10},hidden:true},
           {name:'firstname',index:'lastname', width:100,editable:true,edittype:'text',
               editoptions: {
                    dataInit: function (elem) {
                        myAutocomplete(elem, "${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/grid/autocomplete.action");
                    }                  
           }},
           {name:'lastname',index:'firstname', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}}
          ],
          postData: {
       },
          rowNum:20,
          rowList:[20,40,60],
          height: 200,
          autowidth: true,
          rownumbers: true,
          pager: '#pager',
          sortname: 'id',
          viewrecords: true,
          sortorder: "asc",
          caption:"Users",
          emptyrecords: "Empty records",
          loadonce: false,
          editurl:'${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/grid/edit.action',
          loadError : function(xhr,st,err) { 
              console.log('display error : '+err);  
              jq("#rsperror").html("Type: "+st+"; Response: "+ xhr.status + " "+xhr.statusText);

          },
          loadComplete: function() {
       },
          jsonReader : {
              root: "rows",
              page: "page",
              total: "total",
              records: "records",
              repeatitems: false,
              cell: "cell",
              id: "id"
          }
      });
      jq("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
        {edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:true},
        { },
              { },
              { },
        {
            sopt:['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'gt', 'cn', 'bw', 'ew'],
               closeOnEscape: true,
                multipleSearch: true,
                 closeAfterSearch: true }
      );     
     });
```

Here autocomplete works fine, it lists all the username but it shows behind the editForm on jqgrid. Please suggest a solution.

Thanks & Regards,

Kartik Jajal

Comment: well you need to post the html of your page too.

Comment: I have added jqgrid code so that you can get idea.

Comment: see i asked for markup to post you don't have to do anything with jqgrid code because if you place your autocomplete below jqgrid and try with some css properties to place your autocomplete at a position where you want it to be, we also had same issue with main navigation dropdowns which got behind the jQgrid so we placed our main nav at the bottom and placed with some position absolute and left top properties to its specific position.

Comment: I have solved the problem by setting the z-index property of .ui-front like below .ui-front { z-index: 1000; } in jquery ui css

Comment: Hey then you can answer for this post and accept it as an answer so that you would get some more points on this community as you have just started with 1 point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by setting the z-index property of .ui-front like below .ui-front {   z-index: 1000; } in jquery ui css